# Why does typeahead request 'typeahead-popup.html'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

It makes a network request for it in my code but not [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9zsrvLLfH8hKGwmIeZVv?p=preview) despite my mark-up being the same.

```
 <input typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" type="text" ng-model="state" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typeahead needs a template to show possible solutions to what one is entering.  In your plunker the `//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js` file includes modules that load those templates into angular's `$templateCache` variable.

Comment: Yes I worked it out but my answer was deleted because I asked another question.